# When NGINX deny rule is applied?

Tags: nginx

I have `server 80` which contains `return` and `allow/deny` directives:

```
...
server {

    server_name    dev.monitor.domain.ms;
    listen         80;

    allow 194.***.45;
    allow 37.***.130;
    deny  all;

    return 301 https://dev.monitor.domain.ms$request_uri;
}
...
```

And another `server` with `listen 443`.

So the question here is - why `return 301` works here even for IP which doesn't allow to access?

Finally - I really can't connect, so `allow/deny` works, but...

Example:

> ```
> $ curl -vL dev.monitor.domain.ms
> * About to connect() to dev.monitor.domain.ms port 80 (#0)
> ...
> < HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
>  ...
> < Location: https://dev.monitor.domain.ms/
> ...
> * Issue another request to this URL: 'https://dev.monitor.domain.ms/'                                                                                                                                                                            
> * About to connect() to dev.monitor.domain.ms port 443 (#1)                                                                                                                                                                                      
> *   Trying 40.***.***.237... Connection timed out                                                                                                                                                                                              
> * couldn't connect to host                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
> * Closing connection #1                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
> curl: (7) couldn't connect to host
> ```

Same if add `allow/deny` to `http {}` block. So - when and where these restrictions are checked?

[ngx_http_access_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_access_module.html) documentation doesn't mention anything about this.

Answer (score 0):

`deny` in Nginx is applied to all corresponding locations.
Since you don't have any location defined, it is not applied.

Try putting the redirection into a location:

```
location / {
    return 301 https://dev.monitor.domain.ms$request_uri;
}
```

But beware, that this will not provide security regarding the host directed to.
You will still need to check permissions within the HTTPS host.